# Find a match on specific line

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I'm looking for a way to find a match on a specific line in multiple files, e.g.:

file1.txt:

```
abcd.123
efgh.456
```

file2.txt:

```
ijkl.789
mnop.001
```

I want to return all results for line #2 in each file if it contains a `.` (period).

So far I've tried this cmd:

```
Get-Content *.ini | where-object {"$_" -match '.\\..='}
```

which will return the file name of any file that contains a `.`.

What I want is to return the file name of any file that has a `.` on line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.ini | ? {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName)[1] -like '*.*'
}
```

Since `Get-Content` returns an array of lines, the index `1` will pick the second line from a given file. Also, you should use pattern matching (operator `-like`) rather than a regular expression for this check, because it meets the requirements and provides better performance.

Comment: perfect, I just change [1] to [2] and got the results I want, thanks!

Comment: not sure if this requires a new question but how would I then delete line 2 from all files in the result set?

Comment: @shawnbot That would require a different approach, so yes, it should be a new question.